# What are the names of the kernel threads that represent ISR top-half and bottom-half?

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt, isr

Using google, I know that the linux kernel interrupt handling thread is divided into two parts, the top-half thread and the bottom-half thread.

I want to see on which CPU these two kernel threads reside.

I use top command on `Fedora 19` to find the `interrupt service routine (ISR)`. Taking NIC ISR as example, I can see the following in the top results

```
"627 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 0.000 0.000 0:00.35 irq/76-em1 4"
```

where `em1` is the name of the `NIC`, and its interrupt number is 76 (/proc/interrupts has the information for interrupts). We can see the NIC ISR runs on CPU4.

But on my newly installed `Fedora 26`, the top doesn't show such an entry. The kernel version for `Fedora 26` is `4.11.8-300`. On CentOS7 with kernel 3.10, I still cannot see this information.

How can I find the kernel threads for ISRs and what are the names for ISR threads? Is this caused by linux kernel version?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might help you https://notes.shichao.io/lkd/ch8/#bottom-halves